# Ansible error getting again and again

Tags: ansible-playbook

> ERROR! conflicting action statements: hosts, tasks
>
> The error appears to be in '/home/a899444/aerospike-ansible/roles/java_install/tasks/main.yml': line 1, column 3, but may
> be elsewhere in the file depending on the exact syntax problem.
>
> The offending line appears to be:
>
> ```
> - name: Java installation
>  ^ here
> ```

```yaml
- name: Java installation
  hosts: remote_server
  become: true
  tasks:
    - name: Download the JDK binaries
      get_url:
        url: https://download.java.net/java/GA/jdk18.0.2.1/db379da656dc47308e138f21b33976fa/1/GPL/openjdk-18.0.2.1_linux-x64_bin.tar.gz
        dest: /opt/openjdk-18.0.2.1_linux-x64_bin.tar.gz

    - name: Unzip the downloaded file
      unarchive:
        src: /opt/openjdk-18.0.2.1_linux-x64_bin.tar.gz
        dest: /opt
        remote_src: yes

    - name: Set the JAVA_HOME in /etc/profile file
      lineinfile:
        path: /etc/profile
        state: present
        line: "{{ item }}"
      with_items:
        - 'export JAVA_HOME="/opt/jdk-18.0.2.1"'
        - 'export PATH=$PATH:$JAVA_HOME/bin'

    - name: Reload /etc/profile file
      shell:
        cmd: source /etc/profile
```

Answer (score 0):

In a role the tasks file can only contain tasks, yet you use the format of a playbook. Remove the hosts and everything else from the top level:

```yaml
- name: Download the JDK binaries
  get_url:
    url: https://download.java.net/java/GA/jdk18.0.2.1/db379da656dc47308e138f21b33976fa/1/GPL/openjdk-18.0.2.1_linux-x64_bin.tar.gz
    dest: /opt/openjdk-18.0.2.1_linux-x64_bin.tar.gz

- name: Unzip the downloaded file
  unarchive:
    src: /opt/openjdk-18.0.2.1_linux-x64_bin.tar.gz
    dest: /opt
    remote_src: yes

- name: Set the JAVA_HOME in /etc/profile file
  lineinfile:
    path: /etc/profile
    state: present
    line: "{{ item }}"
  with_items:
    - 'export JAVA_HOME="/opt/jdk-18.0.2.1"'
    - 'export PATH=$PATH:$JAVA_HOME/bin'

- name: Reload /etc/profile file
  shell:
    cmd: source /etc/profile
```

The hosts definition belongs in the playbook where you use the role:

```yaml
hosts: remote_server
become: true
roles:
  - java_install
```

You might want to use some variables instead of fixed paths and filenames though. And that last task is completely useless. Every task starts a new shell where that file is read anyway.

And the [`unarchive` module](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/ansible/builtin/unarchive_module.html) accepts URLs. You can reduce that to two tasks:

```yaml
- name: Unzip JDK
  unarchive:
    src: https://download.java.net/java/GA/jdk18.0.2.1/db379da656dc47308e138f21b33976fa/1/GPL/openjdk-18.0.2.1_linux-x64_bin.tar.gz
    dest: /opt

- name: Set the JAVA_HOME in /etc/profile file
  lineinfile:
    path: /etc/profile
    state: present
    line: "{{ item }}"
  with_items:
    - 'export JAVA_HOME="/opt/jdk-18.0.2.1"'
    - 'export PATH=$PATH:$JAVA_HOME/bin'
```